# Arr.join is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```js
    const combine = (firstName, secondName) => {
    var array1 =firstName.split("")
    var array2 = secondName.split("")
    var firstHalf = array1[array1.length - array1.length]
    var secondHalf = array2.splice(array2.length - array2.length + 1, 
    array2.length - 1)
    var fullArray = firstHalf.concat(secondHalf)
    var finalName = fullArray.join('')
    alert(fullArray)
    }
    const getParameters = () => {
    var name1 = document.getElementById("name1").value;
    var name2 = document.getElementById("name2").value;
    if(name1 && name2)
    combine(name1, name2);
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Made with Thimble</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="name1">
    <input id="name2">
    <button onclick="getParameters()">Combine!</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is all the code I have in my project, but I get these errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: fullArray.join is not a function
>       TypeError: fullArray.join is not a function
>       at combine (https://mozillathimblelivepreview.net/bramble/production/dist/vfs/567615/projects/1134799/script.js:7:29)
>       at getParameters (https.://mozillathimblelivepreview.net/bramble/production/dist/vfs/567615/projects/1134799/script.js:14:5)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (https.://mozillathimblelivepreview.net/bramble/production/dist/vfs/567615/projects/1134799/index.html:1898:168)

Comment: though it's optional, please use semicolons to avoid such cases.

Comment: You need to add what the code is meant to be doing because it's not really clear. Because `firstName` is a string, when you use `concat` - even though `secondName` is an array - `fullArray` will be a string, and there is no String `join` method.

Comment: In other words, what is the expected output of `combine`?

Answer (score 3):

```
var firstHalf = array1[array1.length - array1.length]
```

This part makes no sense as it will always be equal to `array1[0]` and give you one element instead of array.

You want to use

```
 var firstHalf = array1.splice(0, array1.length)
```

Comment: Did you mean `array1.splice(0, array1.length)`? `typeof array1.splice` is `"function"`.

Comment: I still don't know what the OPs function does. If I put in Bob Smith it outputs `b,o,b,m,i,t,h`... :/ That can't be right :)

Comment: @Andy You don't know what [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) does? "The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements."

Comment: No no no. I know what `splice` does. I just don't know why the OP wants that particular output. Instead of "I still don't know what the OPs function does" I should have written "I still don't know what the OPs function is meant to do".

Comment: @Andy Ahh, I gotghya. I tested it too and got the same result. Whatever the function is meant to do isn't very intuitive, and the non descriptive name `combine()` doesn't help.